# D3 js Mercator input type

Tags: json, d3.js

I need to populate the world map using d3 js. Here is my code

```
 $.post("dwr/jsonp/DataFetcher/getJsonData/"+year+"/"+column, { },
              function(data) {
          console.log('map data');

          $('#boodiv').remove();       
          $('#map').empty();


          console.log('loading map');
          console.log(d3.geo);
                  console.log('reply data');
                    console.log(data.reply);


                    var width = 960,
                      height = 960;

                  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                     .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)
                     .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

                   var path = d3.geo.path()
               .projection(projection);



                 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                       .attr("width", width)
                      .attr("height", height);
                       svg.append("path") .attr("d", path);
                       console.log('map is ready to draw');
                var map =svg.append("svg:g").
        attr("class","map");                                                              

           map.selectAll("path").data(data.reply).enter().append("svg:path").
         attr("d",path).append("svg:title").text(
                        function(d) {
                            return d.properties.DGPZ_NAME;
                        });

         });
```

The input I am getting from the DWR response will  be in json Format like this 
      {
         AT: "5.24",
          AU:"7.73"
         }

The problem is the map is not getting populated. My doubt is, will mercator() have some input format?? do we give input in the specific format?? Please Help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to load GeoJSON or TopoJSON data for the map itself.